# Grails Spring Security Core Loggin in User while new User Creation

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have implemented Spring Security Core in my application and according to my work-flow I want to log in the user in the controller when/after it is created without redirecting the user to the spring security login page.
Any suggestions on how may I achieve this..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :-

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username,password);
```